# If vendor name is same as my cell range then return the name of Category in the cell range associated

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a long list of vendors, list contains 10 different vendors. in sheet 2 Created a category for each vendor.

Looking for the function: if vendor in sheet 1 is same as the one in the cell range in sheet 2 then enter the category associated to it.

if(A1=vendors,category,N/a)

Sheet 1 A column: list of 1000 vendors, sheet 2 : A column created a cell range A1:A10=vendors, B column put the category in front of each of the 10 vendors B1:B10.

vendors in Sheet 1 A column. List of my 10 vendors in sheet2 a1:a10. categories in sheet2 B1:b10. vlookup(a1,sheet2a1:a10,2,false)

What is the best function to use.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to introduce you to the [vlookup function](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/VLOOKUP-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65).  It will be a great friend to you!

You can also wrap it with the [iferror function](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/IFERROR-function-f59bacdc-78bd-4924-91df-a869d0b08cd5) to set a default if nothing is found.